# Get key board height in android QML

Tags: android, qt, qml

Am trying to get the height of the virtual keyboard in android using Qt.inputMethod::keyboardRectangle but i keep getting unexpected results (the Qt.inputMethod::keyboardRectangle.height is larger(almost 2 times) than the virtual keyboad height).

i have noticed in the Qt documentation

**Qt.InputMethod::keyboardRectangle**

***" Virtual keyboard's geometry in window coordinates."***

Then if the geometry is in window coodinates..then how can i convert them to qml units...

Thanks

Tried with Qt.InputMethod::keyboardRectangle but getting wrong results

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I had faced w this issue also, although the tstatic inputMethod instance returns the correct size of keyboard rectangle for iOS, android hadn't seem working at all. You could try to acquire keyboard size by doing JNI calls